# How can I extract blocks of Bytes from a int32_t and store it in a int16_t or int8_t using c?

Tags: c, binary, byte, converters, stdint

If I have, for example:

```
int32_t x = 572662306;  /* 00100010001000100010001000100010 */
```

I want to store the the two most significant bytes in an `int8_t`:

```
00100010 (base 2) = 34 (base 10)
```

Or the four most significant bytes in an `int16_t`:

```
0010001000100010 (base 2) = 8738 (base 10)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know about the bitwise and shift operators? 4-bit bytes aren't supported by standard C, either. Do you mean nibble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very uninteresting number to extract bytes out of. All the bytes are `0x22`. Regardless, here's one way to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
   int32_t num = 572662306;

   int8_t num2;
   int8_t num3;

   int16_t num4;
   int16_t num5;

   printf("num in hex: 0x%x\n", num);

   num2 = (num >> 24);
   num3 = (num >> 16);
   num4 = (num >> 16);
   num5 = num;

   printf("num2 in hex: 0x%x\n", num2);
   printf("num3 in hex: 0x%x\n", num3);
   printf("num4 in hex: 0x%x\n", num4);
   printf("num5 in hex: 0x%x\n", num5);
}
```

Output:

```
num in hex: 0x22222222
num2 in hex: 0x22
num3 in hex: 0x22
num4 in hex: 0x2222
num5 in hex: 0x2222
```

**PS**

You have to be careful about bit-shifting negative numbers. It's better to perform bit shifting on unsigned numbers. If `num` is negative, the results of bit shifting to the right is implementation defined. From the C99 standard (6.5.7/5):

> The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If `E1` has an unsigned type or if `E1` has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of `E1 /`2<sup>E2</sup>. **If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.**

Comment: to be a little bit pedantic: you should use unsigned types, otherwise you can get unexpected output if one of the MSBs is set: https://ideone.com/eQ8fsL